# Como calcular atraso em dias no Access

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

Hoje utilizo a fórmula `=DIAS(HOJE();H2)` para calcular o tempo de atraso de pendências no Excel:

[image: Planilha Atual - excel]

Porém essa fonte eu extraio do Access, alguém sabe a sintaxe para montar essa fórmula no Access?

Comment: Eu conseguindo ja deixar essa coluna pronta no Access, me economizaria o tempo e trabalho de precisar criar uma coluna nova no Excell toda vez q extraio. ( faço essa extração diariamente)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar a função `now()`, a fórmula ficaria assim:

```
Tempo_Pendencia: Round(Now() - [Data_inicio_pendencia], 0)
```

a fórmula `Round()` com zero elimina decimai.